iframe which loads the other domain doesn't work in chrome
In my site, it uses iframe to load the view of other cross-site domain and it works in Edge(IE mode).
However, it doesn't work in Chrome.
After searching every minute, I found out that the default SameSite cookie policy of Chrome is 'Lax'.
When I open the console it shows that
"This Set-Cookie header didn't specify a "SameSite" attribvute and was default to "SameSite=Lax", and was blocked because it came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation. The Set-Cookie had to have been set with "SameSite=None" to enable cross-site usage."
Is there a solution which fixes the problem in my site only? I have no privileges that requests to the other domain though.
Any tricks welcome!
Thank you for reading.

This question is similar to: How Samesite cookie settings works with iframes. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
